# Nuxt default progress bar become red when navigate to page no asyncData or fetch

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Im using default nuxt progress bar. Change the colour to blue. Before this when I navigate to page that use asynData or fetch its show blue color, but now I change when created then fetch but the progress bar become red not blue. Im running universal mode.

Comment: red means you have an error

Comment: @Ifaruki I also think so, but when I check console or network no error at all. Any other hints?

Comment: no idea. are you sure there is no error?

Comment: @Ifaruki ya you're right, actually there is an error. Triggered by watch query at first time enter page. Thx for convincing me to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the loading configuration in the nuxt.config.js file, or a page routing file
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading